# How to make rounded edges of a face

Tags: interface, edges, bevel

I want to make these 2 inner faces with rounded edges like the left image

At the right image I used Ctrl+B to make the outer edges of this board rounded but I can't apply this to  inner face as the board itself is a cube with some modification[image]

Comment: If you want to smoothen geometry corners you need more geometry. In this case it would be beveling corner vertices of that inner red rectangle. After that one will have to get rid of Ngons.

Comment: can u attach the file

Comment: Check this topology. It's mostly manual work. https://imgur.com/0I8gMfF

Answer (score 3):

For your example this could do the job:

1. Enable *LoopTools* addon in the *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> > *Addons*)
2. Select the outer vertices
3. Apply *Relax* function with *Linear Interpolation*

[image]

Comment: It will distort whole rectangular shape. OP asked about rounded corners.

Comment: Still, I think it should work for the case illustrated in the second image.

Answer (score 0):

(tested with blender 2.9)

goto edit-mode

select only the 4 corner-vertices of the inner rectangle.

press CTRL + B

then, immediately press V  (for vertex mode)

use mouse and scroll wheel to round the vertex

[image: blender3d - rounding corners of an inner rectangle]

video (external link):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT3GN.jpg